# Tikz mindmaps sharing children

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, mindmaps

Is it possible to have two mindmaps that share children?
This is what I would like to have:

Concept 1 is blue, and has some children. 
Concept 2 is red, and has some children. 
Concept 1 and two share one child, which is purple.

And this is what I have so far:
Concept 1 is blue, and has some children.
Concept 2 is blue, and has some children.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[small mindmap,concept color=blue!80]
  \node [concept] {Root concept 1}
    child[clockwise from=270] {node[concept] {child}}
    child[clockwise from=270] {node[concept] {child}};
  \node [concept] at (5,0) {Root concept 2}
    child[clockwise from=225] {node[concept] {child}}
    child[grow=0 ] {node[concept] {child}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a scope for the color, and opacity, and a bit manual positioning of the root nodes, such as:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[small mindmap,concept color=blue!80]
  \node [concept] {Root concept 1}
    child[clockwise from=0] {node[concept] {child}}
    child[clockwise from=270] {node[concept] {child}};
  \begin{scope}[concept color=red!80]
    \node [concept] at (5.6,0) {Root concept 2}
      child[clockwise from=180] {node[concept,opacity=0.5] {child}}
      child[grow=230 ] {node[concept] {child}}
      child[grow=270 ] {node[concept] {child}};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: mindmap]

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `circle connection bar` path as explained in section 39.4.3 of the Tikz manual in combination with the scoping trick by @Stefan, like so:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[small mindmap,concept color=blue!80]
  \node (n1) [concept] {Root concept 1}
    child[clockwise from=270] {node[concept] {child}}
    child[clockwise from=270] {node[concept] {child}};
  \begin{scope}[concept color=red]
    \node (n2) [concept] at (5,0) {Root concept 2}
      child[clockwise from=225] {node[concept, concept color=magenta] (c1) {child}}
      child[grow=0 ] {node[concept] {child}};
  \end{scope}

 \path (n1) to [circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!80) to (magenta)] (c1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This results in:

[image]

The connection between `Root Concept 2` and the shared child can be made a gradient too, or you can just change `switch color` to `color`.