# Mindmap: Common child

Tags: mindmaps

Consider the MWE (copied from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144828/38244)):

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[small mindmap, outer sep=0pt, text=black]

\begin{scope}[concept color=brown!30]
\node (right) at (2,0) [concept] {Right}
  [clockwise from=70]
  child { node[concept] {R.1} }
  child { node[concept] {R.2} }
;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[concept color=green!40!black!30]
\node (left) at (-2,0) [concept] {Left}
  [counterclockwise from=210]
  child { node[concept] {L.1}  }
  child { node[concept] {L.2} }
;
\end{scope}

\path (left) to[circle connection bar switch color=from (green!40!black!30) to (brown!30)] (right) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now I want that, `R.1` and `L.1` will be merged to a single node. In other words, the two root nodes will share a common child. Any advice will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

The linked [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41620/tikz-mindmaps-sharing-children) asks the same problem. However, I would like to point out that the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41623/38244) to this question does not (in my humble understanding) solve the problem. It intelligently places one child on top of another, creating an impression that a child is shared. Apparently, it needs manual processing to place the node in the middle (which can be tedious, as can be seen from the [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144823/38244)).

Comment: Maybe you can find some inspiration here: [Tikz mindmaps sharing children](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41620/134144)

Comment: How about omitting L.1 and drawing a path from R.1 to Left (after you rearrange the position of the child nodes a bit to make R.1 in between Left and Right)?

Comment: @Marijn "rearrange the position" -- You mean doing it manually? I would like to avoid any manual processing... :-)

Comment: @pushpen.paul it is already manual now (`clockwise from=70`), so that would not be a big difference I think? Change 70 into 150 or so and see how it looks.

Comment: I agree with @Marijn. How is `\node (left) at (-2,0) ` not manual? Or are you asking if one can compute the relevant shift from pgf keys? This is of course possible.

Comment: Mindmaps are formally trees, but what you want is not a tree, so what you're asking is not  likely to be doable automatically.

Comment: @AlanMunn Oh, OK! Now I understand!